# Google Datastore Querying Set

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, nosql

I have following entities:

```
public class Group implements Serializable {
  private Key id;
}

public class LsUser implements Serializable {
  private Set<Key> myGroups;
}
```

Each group has its own key in Datastore, in a User I store set of keys of Groups to which user belongs to.
Question is how can I get list of all users who has specific key in a set of groups? I suppose I can do it creating Query with Filter similar to next one:

```
Query<Entity> query = Query.entityQueryBuilder()
            .kind(User.class)
            .filter(StructuredQuery.PropertyFilter.eq("property", value)
            .build();
```

Comment: The code you have there looks correct -- is it working for you?

Comment: kind() method takes a String arg... guessing this sample code won't compile. Otherwise, looks good.